# COPY TO xxxx.xls TYPE XLS (VFP 8.0 SP1)

Tags: visual-foxpro

I downloading table from SQL 2008 using VFP 8.0 (SP1) using command: 
COPY TO xxx TYPE XLS 
Some of the data in the excel is disappearing.

Example, 
Table in SQL: Cus(ID int(4), CusNam VARCHAR(35))

When i issue the following command at VFP Forms:

**(a) COPY TO xxx TYPE FOX2x [Data display correctly as following]**

*ID CusNam

1  ABC

2  DEF*

**(b) COPY TO xxx TYPE XLS [2nd Record disappear]**

*ID CusNam

1

2  DEF*

Appreciate for any helps!

Answer (score 1):

For testing, I would just copy to VFP directly as a table to see if THAT writes out correctly.  Then you can copy it out from there..  Are you using the view designer and connection, or manually controlling via something like

```
nHandle = SQLConnect( "YourConnectionStringInfo" )
SQLExec( nHandle, "Select * from YourSQLTable", "IntoLocalVFPCursor" )
select IntoLocalVFPCursor
COPY TO PermanentLocalVFPTable
USE PermanentLocalVFPTable
BROWSE
SQLDisconnect( nHandle )
```

In all the years of VFP / SQL, I don't ever recall any such data loss.  However, when doing a dump to Excel, there is a limit of records to 65535... the max of older Excel file format capacity which was never extended since.